# Understanding polynomial time with N queens example

Tags: polynomials, algorithms

Im having difficulty understanding polynomial time complexity.
I've read many explanations but there are no examples given to make complete sense, hence I try asking here with a clear example.

I quote polynomial time explanation from one site I was reading

> An algorithm is said to be solvable in polynomial time if the number of steps required to complete the algorithm for a given input is O(n^k) for some nonnegative integer k, where n is the complexity of the input.

Now lets say I have N queens problem where N = 8
queens and NxN board = 64

if I try to fit this problem into the explanation above, then what is n and what is k?

Comment: To speak of polynomial time, one needs a family of questions indexed by some parameter, $n$.  Here you have a specific numerical question.  Of course, you might be thinking of the problem with $n$ queens on an $n\times n$ board in which case the parameter would, of course, be $n$.  $k$ needs to be determined from the algorithm.

Comment: I'm researching this in relation Simple Hill Climb Algorithm. Is there a specific k? @lulu

Comment: I don't know if the problem has been solved via that algorithm or not.  [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12682/is-the-n-queens-problem-np-hard) is a link that contains some references to polynomial time solutions.  You'll see, I think, that the point has been to show that there was $\textit {some}$ polynomial time algorithm (that was very far from obvious)  and I am not sure the references make an effort to minimize $k$.  I see that they can handle, say, $n\sim 500,000$ which seems pretty good to me.